# Get user phone number in firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've written `https.onCall firebase cloud function` like

```
exports.sampleFunction=functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
console.log(context.auth.token.phoneNumber+" ***** "+context.auth.token.email+" ***** "+context.auth.token.name);
  return userTransaction.sampleFunction(data,context).then(function(message){
    console.log(message);
  })
});
```

I'm storing the user's `phone number` and can fetch phone number at client using

```
FirebaseAuth auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user=auth.getCurrentUser();
        user.getPhoneNumber();
```

When I'm calling this function, I can see that `email` and `name` is getting printed at `firebase cloud functions logs` but `phoneNumber` is undefined.
How to get `user phone number` through `context` in `firebase cloud functions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following, using `admin.auth().getUser(uid)` should work:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
....

exports.sampleFunction = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {

  return admin.auth().getUser(context.auth.uid)
    .then(userRecord => {
      const phoneNumber = userRecord.phoneNumber;
      console.log(phoneNumber+" ***** "+context.auth.token.email+"      ***** "+context.auth.token.name);   
      return userTransaction.sampleFunction(data,context)    //Not sure what this is doing, I just chained it with the previous and next then(s). Modify as necessary....
    })
    .then(message => {
      console.log(message);
      return { message: message };
    })

});
```

See the corresponding docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUser) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord). Note that `getUser()` returns a promise.

Comment: this will increase the execution time for firebase cloud, eventually impacting billing at month end. But seems there is no other way to get the user phone number from firebase.

Answer (score 4):

So much easier:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const phone = context.auth.token.phone_number;
})
```